# C#'s RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter equivalent in Node.js

Tags: c#, node.js, jwt

Need the equivalent of the code below, I am using same code [for the token verification](http://techqa.info/programming/tag/jwt?after=38311108).

```cs
RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter rsaDeformatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(rsa);
rsaDeformatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");
bool validSignature = rsaDeformatter.VerifySignature(hash, signaturePart)
```

What is the equivalent of the code above in Node.js?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this Node.js example, and see if it helps you:

[(Node.js) Verify JWT Using an RSA Public Key (RS256, RS384, RS512)](https://www.example-code.com/nodejs/jwt_rsa_verify.asp)